# how to download files from a placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

I have a placeholder control where i have added the files from my folder. 
I have also binded a check box with each file
How i can download the files if checkbox is clicked.

```
string strDir = Request.QueryString["d"] == null ? FileBrowerProperty.IntialPath : Request.QueryString["d"];

//read the directory
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strDir);
//read the subdirectories inside the parent directory
DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = DirInfo.GetDirectories();
//read the files in the parent directory
FileInfo[] Files = DirInfo.GetFiles();

foreach (DirectoryInfo di in subDirs)
{
    ListItem listitem1 = new ListItem(di.FullName);
    // <a href='more.php' onclick='show_more_menu()'>More >>></a>
    //add the directory info to our table 
    LiteralControl lcFolders = new LiteralControl(@"<TR><TD style='WIDTH: 20px'><input type='checkbox' id='"
       + @di.FullName
       + "'>Directory</TD><TD style='WIDTH:350px'><a href='webform1.aspx?d=" 
       + @di.FullName + "'>" + di.Name + "</a></TD><TD style='WIDTH: 150px'>" 
       + di.CreationTime + "</TD><TD style='WIDTH: 150px'>" + di.LastWriteTime 
       + "</TD></TR>");

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lcFolders);  
}
```

How to download files from a placeholder control if checkbox is clicked
if its not possible then plz tell me that how can i loop through the contents of the placeholder
so that i can findout the checkbox and then supply the file name to download the file

Comment: It seems a if you are potentially exposing every file on your web server by blindly accepting any user input for the initial directory path.  Please be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# expert but with jQuery you could simply do this:
JS:

```
function download(d) {
    if (d == 'Select document' && d !== '') return;
    window.location = d;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <select id="select_download" name="download" onChange="download(this.value); "> 
       <option value="">Select file</option>    
       <option id="sourcefile_download" value="http://..."> Sourcefile</option>                          
    </select>
```

Well this example is about select a dropdown but you could simply rewrite it for check boxes I guess. Hope that helps somehow.